# Properly customizing login/register form

Tags: customization, login, wp-login-form

I'm working on a customized login form for WordPress. I noticed that it's pretty difficult to achieve what I wanted.

Here's the HTML of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php">
    <div class="loginbox_fields">
        <div class="loginbox_field"><input type="text" name="log" id="user_login"  value="" placeholder="<?php _e('Username'); ?>"/></div>
        <div class="loginbox_field"><input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" value="" placeholder="<?php _e('Password'); ?>"/></div>
        <div class="loginbox_text">
            <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  <?php checked( $rememberme ); ?> />
            <label for="remember"><?php esc_attr_e('Remember Me'); ?></label>
        </div>
        <a href="/nojs.html" class="loginbox_button form_submit" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Log In'); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e('Log In'); ?></a>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="first_column">Not registered?</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Forgot password?</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="first_column"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?action=register" class="loginbox_stdbutton" title="Register">Register</a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?action=lostpassword" class="loginbox_stdbutton" title="Reset Password">Reset Password</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Due to style requirement, I put `div` wraps around `input` boxes and the submit button is an anchor tag. According to [the document](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Login_Hooks), `wp_login_form` and its hooks will not be able to implement this design.

So I followed the suggestions on this question (I asked) [Custom user profile, registration, login page with theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84938/custom-user-profile-registration-login-page-with-theme) , and got something close to http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/ . Basically, it allows you to put the login form anywhere you want, but still points back to `wp-login.php` when submitted.

But it has one major flaw. When login is incorrect, it points you back to `wp-login.php`. Like this [demo](http://digwp.com/custom-login-demo/), if you click "Login" without entering anything, it leads you back to the default `wp-login.php` form.

I'm currently putting the above form in one of the custom pages. I had a filter hooked to `template_include` and used this HTML code as the login form. I only wanted to change the style, I'm not planning on adding functions.

What does it take to implement this login form design? Shall I start from wp-login.php and change it? If so, how do I start (in terms of putting in the theme and form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect back to your custom login form after login fails try this code:

```
// hook failed login
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail'); 

function my_front_end_login_fail($username){
    // Get the reffering page, where did the post submission come from?
    $referrer = add_query_arg('login', false, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if(!empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin')){
        // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
        wp_redirect($referrer . '?login=failed'); 
    exit;
    }
}
```

You'll have to check also for an empty password or login - when login form from frontend (your custom login form) is submitted empty, you'll end up on standard wp-login.php again. To prevent this, append this code:

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'my_frontend_login_no_pass_no_username' );

function my_frontend_login_no_pass_no_username(){
    $referrer = add_query_arg('login', false, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if ( (!isset($_REQUEST['user_login']) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['user_login'] ) && trim( $_REQUEST['user_login'] ) == '' ) ) || (!isset($_REQUEST['user_pass']) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['user_pass'] ) && trim( $_REQUEST['user_pass'] ) == '' ) ) ){
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg('login', 'failed', $referrer) ); 
        exit; 
    }   
}
```

If you're interested in a proper login after registration fails too, check my [blogpost on this topic.](http://david.binda.cz/ultimate-guide-on-redirect-to-custom-page-after-login-register-fails)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You pointed the right direction. I'll read your post further. Although after digging a bit, it turns out that `wp_login_failed` will only be triggered when both username and password is filled. I found a post here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_login_failed-not-working-if-only-one-field-is-filled-out?replies=4 which mentioned `wp_authenticate`. I ended up hooking both, and changed `wp_authenticate` to match my particular requirement.

Comment: Again, thank you for the elegant solution on `login_head`.

Comment: You're welcome. I've spent few hours on this problem just few days ago, and I'm glad I can share my knowledge and save other's time ;)